# How to use the Unit test tool comes with VS2008 Pro to test a C++ proj?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Here's what i've done:
i choose Test -> create new test -> wizard
Then it asked me to enter a proj name.  i did.
then it told me to select a source proj to test, i chose my working proj... but...
a warning dialog popped up saying : "Unknown virtual address 0" and refuse to continue.

i tried rebuilding my source proj many times... no luck

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kolbis/archive/2007/07/08/Visual-C_2B002B00_-Unit-Testing-in-VS.aspx) you will found full description of VS tests usage in c++. Citate - If your production code is written in Visual C++, you can generate unit tests only if your product uses the /clr:safe compiler option.